# How to get the element of dynamic assigned id in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have following code in ASP.Net MVC

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.users, @Model.User, new {
  id = "UserIds" + @Model.ID
})
```

How can I find the id of this element?

Answer (score 0):

Either assign the id to a variable

```
@{ var id = "UserIds" + Model.ID; }
```

and use the variable in the helper

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.users, @Model.User, new { id = id })
```

and anywhere else you need to use the value.

Alternatively, you may decide to rely on the framework itself to generate an id for you which you can get with

```
@Html.IdFor(m => m.users)
```

this will give you the same id that the framework will generate and assign to the dropdown when using the DropDownListFor helper.